# Dompdf Failed to open stream lib fonts Permission on Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I created laravel project that work fine on my local windows pc. Once I upload to Centos7 server(via SSH). I have problem on dompdf file export. I got an error 'fopen(/var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/1efc692e8d059670778f16e902f6d711.ufm): failed to open stream: Permission denied'. Picture of errror https://ibb.co/ZShGG2X

```
    #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'fopen(/var/www/...', '/var/www/html/s...', 45, Array)

    #1 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/AdobeFontMetrics.php(45): fopen('/var/www/html/s...', 'w+')

    #2 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/TrueType/File.php(361): FontLib\AdobeFontMetrics->write('/var/www/html/s...', NULL)

    #3 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/FontMetrics.php(212): FontLib\TrueType\File->saveAdobeFontMetrics('/var/www/html/s...')

    #4 /var/www/html/srp/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Stylesheet.php(1537): Dompdf\FontMetrics->registerFont(Array, 'http://110.49.7...', NULL)
```

Thank you for all advice.

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this issue?